# ESP32 AysncWebServer

Tags: webserver, iot, esp32

I am having issue with my ESP32 WROOM board while using AsyncWebServer.
the url to access the code is ip/inline?a=5
the number a=5 controls how many characters the AsyncWebServer will send to the client.
When I access it over browser, if number of characters is 1-500 range, it works fine and browser works by displaying data in the window. However,when I reach near 600 and above, either the board resets or stops respondings for a while and browser window never resumes.
Initially I though it is an issue with the memory as a String cannot have 2000+ characters, so it is already well below

Can any one tell me how Can resolve it? Also, I want to display a very long HTML string to the browser, may have 10K characters. Can I do this? How? It is in combination with the other application code. I have copied and simplified it. The message by the compiler after comiling the actual app shows that I have lots of memory still available.

My code is here

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WebServer.h>
#include <ESPmDNS.h>

const char* ssid = "****";
const char* password = "***";
;

WebServer server(80);

const int led = 13;

void handleRoot() {
  digitalWrite(led, 1);
  server.send(200, "text/plain", "hello from esp32!");
  digitalWrite(led, 0);
}

void handleNotFound() {
  digitalWrite(led, 1);
  String message = "File Not Found\n\n";
  message += "URI: ";
  message += server.uri();
  message += "\nMethod: ";
  message += (server.method() == HTTP_GET) ? "GET" : "POST";
  message += "\nArguments: ";
  message += server.args();
  message += "\n";
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < server.args(); i++) {
    message += " " + server.argName(i) + ": " + server.arg(i) + "\n";
  }
  server.send(404, "text/plain", message);
  digitalWrite(led, 0);
}

void setup(void) {
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led, 0);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("");

  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  if (MDNS.begin("esp32")) {
    Serial.println("MDNS responder started");
  }

  server.on("/", handleRoot);

  server.on("/inline", []() 
  {
        String content="\0";
        String random_data=F("<br />Apart from counting words and characters, our online editor can help you to improve 1234<br />");
        
    
      for (int i=1;i<=100*9;i++)
      {
        //serial.print(i); 
        content=content+i;
        content=content+random_data;
      }
      

    
    server.send(200, "text/html", content);
  });

  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);

  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}

void loop(void) {
  server.handleClient();
  delay(2);//allow the cpu to switch to other tasks
}
```

Comment: Using String and a lot String concatenations like there is no tomorrow is sure a source of heap memory fragmentation. See my [answer and explanation](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/75745/how-to-fix-memory-leak-code-in-esp8266-nodemcu-caused-by-string-concenation/75758#75758) and modify your code accordingly.

Comment: thanks. But if I output it on the serial, it shows the content. Just issue on browser.

Comment: Maybe my message is too subtle and maybe you don't really read my answer or understand it. So let me try again, your String concatenation in the `for (int i=1;i<=100*9;i++)` loop is a source of heap fragmentation(i.e. you are running out of memory) because of your String concatenation in `content=content+random_data;`. Add `Serial.println(ESP.getFreeHeap());` after that line of code to see it yourself!

Comment: sure, thanks for clarification. Let me do this and I will back with the results. :)

Answer (score 0):

The code is not formatted properly.

**First of all here is a correct model with an example:**

```
server.on("/inline", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    // Check if we have a param.
    // If not, return with 500 internal error.
    if( !request->hasParam("a") ){
        request->send(500, "text/plain", "Please fill param!");
    }
    AsyncWebParameter* p = request->getParam("a");
    int charAmountRequested = p->value().toInt();

    // Create a char array with the requested size.
    char content[charAmountRequested];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < charAmountRequested; i++){
        content[i] = 'g';
    }
    request->send(200, "text/html", content);
});
```

**If you absolutely want to do it with String, here is an other example:**

```
server.on("/inline", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    // Check if we have a param.
    // If not, return with 500 internal error.
    if( !request->hasParam("a") ){
        request->send(500, "text/plain", "Please fill param!");
    }
    String content;
    AsyncWebParameter* p = request->getParam("a");
    int charAmountRequested = p->value().toInt();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < charAmountRequested; i++){
        content += "g";
    }
    request->send(200, "text/html", content);
});
```

*Note: These are untested codes but it should give you an idea.*